# Can I ask for algorithm implementation examples?

Tags: discussion, scope

There is an algorithm with a short description on Wikipedia, but only a basic idea with time and space complexities and a bunch of scientific papers with a lot of variations of the algorithm.

I want to see a real-life implementation of the algorithm before implementing it myself. A link to a GitHub project is the answer I seek.

Can I ask such a question on Stack Overflow?

Comment: "*link on github project is the answer I seek.*" that's asking for offsite resources. Moreover, it produces a Q&A which is extremely highly likely to stop being useful or intelligible at some point if the links go down or are unreachable.

Comment: 'I want to see a real life implementation of the algorithm' may be understood as if you would ask for code. That probably won't be well received.

Comment: Is an entire (external) example really the only thing you could be asking for? As there already are several published versions, can't you *focus* on a *specific* pain point of understanding the algorithm, for example?

Comment: see also [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7538/31260)

Comment: "link on github project is the answer I seek" - well search engines like Google, Bing and Duck Duck Go are really good at finding stuff on Github... Surely said algorithm has a name since it is on wikipedia.

Answer (score 7):

You can't ask for a link to a GitHub project. Answers have to be self-contained, i.e., answered here.

If you need a GitHub project then it's likely to be too broad, so even if you asked for an answer here it probably wouldn't be well received.

Try working on it yourself instead. Likely to be better received is to ask when you get stuck on some particular part of the implementation. Especially if you've tried and failed to find an answer that would unstick you here already.

Comment: Not a full github project but something like a several hundred lines module hidden in the guts of some database. I'm pretty sure a person with expierence in database kernel coding can solve my problem very quickly.

Comment: It's unlikely that someone else will want to write several hundred lines of code for you, especially if you can't be bothered to try writing any yourself.

Answer (score 5):

Even if someone is willing to write "several hundred lines...", that is not the purpose of this site. It is not a personal help site but rather a question and answer site. If you can create a *focused* (this being key) programming question, one that would be helpful future visitors, one answerable without having to write pages of code or write a tutorial, then you may ask about this topic, but if you're asking for example code, then that is overly broad and asking for external resources, and would not be on-topic.

So to sum up, the answer would be: "it depends" on the specifics of your actual question whether it is to be considered on-topic or off-topic.